# how to make firefox restart required when a webextension is being removed or disabled

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing an firefox WebExtensions，and for some reason, I need firefox restart required when the user remove or disable the extensions.

[I did see some extensions have this feature like that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2MT1.jpg)

So if someone know about this, please help. Thanks.

Comment: It should not be necessary to restart Firefox when you install a WebExtension.

Answer (score 1):

Only [Legacy Firefox Add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Porting_a_legacy_Firefox_add-on) need restart Firefox to enable. [It](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2MT1.jpg)'s a hint from Firefox instead of Extension. The extension which based WebExtensions needless to that.

AFAICS, it seems that the WebExtensions has no reason to need that restart Firefox, and the WebExtensions has no power to do that restart Firefox.